# PHP header not shows custom message if code is 204

Tags: php, http-headers

I'm writing and API and I throw and Exception that calls a method to compose the header to return. If there isn't content I throw an Exception with a custom message and code 204.

```
throw new Exception("my message", 204);
```

And the method that composes the header

```
if ($status_codes[$code] !== null) {
    $status_string = $code . ' ' . $status_codes[$code];
    header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ' ' . $status_string, true, $code);

    if ($code != 200) die(json_encode(["code" => $code, "message" => $message]));

}
```

The problem is that when I use the code 204 I only show the status of the response that's a `204 No content` but my message with the code is not shown. I tried with the code 400 and it shows the custom message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The 204 response MUST NOT include a message-body, and thus is always terminated by the first empty line after the header fields.

**[RFC 2616](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)**

Need anymore words ? :)

Comment: Thanks for the link, now I understand it. Then can I use a different code that can be appropriate to return a message when there is no data found from DB?

Comment: That is correct, you can. though If you stick to 204 then any compliant api client will know not to expect a text message with it so that is also fine in itself